# Why are there unused pages in my SQLite database?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

If I look in the database settings of my database (with SQLite Manager) I have a freelist_count of 16. According to [this source](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_freelist_count) the freelist count is

> the number of unused pages in the database file

What is meant with unused pages and why are there unusued pages? Is it bad to have a freelist count of greater than zero? What can I do to reduce the number to zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [SQLite FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html):

> (12) I deleted a lot of data but the database file did not get any smaller. Is this a bug?
>
> No. When you delete information from an SQLite database, the unused
>   disk space is added to an internal "free-list" and is reused the next
>   time you insert data. The disk space is not lost. But neither is it
>   returned to the operating system.
>
> If you delete a lot of data and want to shrink the database file, run
>   the VACUUM command. VACUUM will reconstruct the database from scratch.
>   This will leave the database with an empty free-list and a file that
>   is minimal in size. Note, however, that the VACUUM can take some time
>   to run (around a half second per megabyte on the Linux box where
>   SQLite is developed) and it can use up to twice as much temporary disk
>   space as the original file while it is running.
>
> As of SQLite version 3.1, an alternative to using the VACUUM command
>   is auto-vacuum mode, enabled using the auto_vacuum pragma.

There's nothing bad in having some free pages, unless they take significant amount of space. It is up to you to decide where ends the “nothing bad” and starts the “significant”, depending on the needs of your application.

Comment: If I enter `VACUUM;` the database grows from 4,3 MB to nearly 6 MB. Do you know why? Follow up question: When should I use the `VACUUM` command? After every `DELETE`?

Comment: Here I found some good links: [`VACUUM`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) and [`AUTO_VACUUM`](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_auto_vacuum).

Comment: @testing Did you wait for it to end? It uses more space while running.

Comment: How do I know if it is finished? I execute the command and half a second later SQLite Manager says `not an error`.

Comment: @testing For example, run `VACUUM` if you've got many megabytes (or above 50% of total DB size) of free pages and you're sure they will not be reused. It's like defragmenting a hard drive, you don't do it every day.

Comment: Seems SQLite Manage is not suitable for that type of command. Sqliteman and sqliteadmin works fine.